# Prevet words breaking in wordpress theme when showing list of posts

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.

In mobile view, the words are broken when shown with image.

"Key Points:" should either be shown as separate words, or should be moved to next space (or below image".

It tried different methods but got the same results.

I added `word-break: keep-all !important;` inside <p style=". . .> and inside CSS in inspect. I added it on "additional CSS" part of the WP theme. But I still see same results.

What should I add in "additional CSS" part to make these words not break inside?

The link is here:
https://www.financefixed.com/blog

[image]